# Conditional @AttributeOverride Hibernate annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables `FoodAudit` and `IngredientAudit` that mirror (plus some additional columns) the tables `Food` and `Ingredient` as part of a revisions system I am working on. Ideally, both of these tables would map to `RevisionDetail<T>` objects in my domain model, but that's proving a bit tricky. To accomplish this, I want to embed either a `Food` or `Ingredient` object as shown below.

```
@Entity
public class RevisionDetail<T> {        
    @Column(name="RevisionId")
    private int revisionId;

    @Column(name="Operation")
    private Operation operation;

    @Embedded
    private T entity;

    public RevisionDetail() {}
}
```

Rather than `Id`, though, on the audit tables the column is `FoodId` or `IngredientId` on the audit tables. I would think to use the `@AttributeOverride` annotation, but the column name changes depending on whether it is a `Food` or `Ingredient` object. How might I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).

If you want to implement it by our own I suggest to use inheritance with `@MappedSuperClass` annotation on base type that will be extended by all auditable subclasses.

```
@MappedSuperClass
publci class BaseEntity{
    @Id 
    Long id;
}
```

Than it is possible to map entity to revision:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fk_id")
BaseEntity entity;
```

---

@AttributeOverride can override only attributes of @Column annotation. Column name.

@Embeded can by used for @Embedable class which is not entity and does not has own table. Fields of embedable will by part of owning entity/table